# Store result into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying below code

```
declare @mdt table (a date, srno int)

declare @a int=1
declare @b int 
declare @hrk date

select @b = count(*)
from hrk_test
where report_date between '01-oct-2020'
and '31-dec-2020'

insert into @mdt
select report_date, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by report_date) srno
from hrk_test
where report_date between '01-oct-2020'
and '31-dec-2020'

while @a<@b+1
begin
    select @hrk=a from @mdt where srno=@a

    select * into #temp 
    from (
        select LBrCode, rtrim(substring(PrdAcctId,1,8)) prdcd, Balance4, @hrk xdate
            , rank() over (partition by LBrCode,PrdAcctId order by CblDate desc) rnk
        from cbl where CblDate <= @hrk  and floor(substring(PrdAcctId,17,8)) = 0
    ) x
    where rnk=1 and prdcd='CC' -- and LBrCode=1

    set @a=@a+1
end
```

How do I save result in a temp table?

I tried `select * into #temp` from after `select @hrk=a from @mdt where srno=@a` but able to save only first record.

I post here a sample data

```
create table cbl ( LBrCode int,PrdAcctId char(32),CblDate datetime,Balance4 numeric(18,2))
```

records for cbl

```
INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-01', 8482069)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-02', 8276845)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-04', 8514655)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-05', 8158793)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-06', 8146670)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-07', 7799478)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-08', 7860562)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-09', 7988995)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-11', 7571018)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-12', 7985069)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-13', 8078286)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-14', 8328886)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-15', 7403299)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-16', 7398840)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-18', 7001180)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-01', 4175229)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-02', 4342455)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-03', 4401537)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-04', 4320289)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-06', 4459020)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-07', 4394631)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-08', 4421792)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-09', 4648368)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-10', 4022792)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-11', 4091647)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-13', 4152613)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-14', 4249339)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-15', 4174540)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-16', 4370915)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-18', 4164375)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-01', 6328520)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-03', 6037587)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-04', 6364095)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-05', 6149323)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-06', 6318445)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-07', 6484416)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-08', 6364717)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-10', 6250361)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-11', 6449951)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-12', 6497133)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-13', 6624645)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-14', 6428226)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-15', 6694113)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-17', 6966289)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-18', 6628651)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-01', 9927031)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-03', 9351583)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-04', 9781888)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-05', 9768333)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-06', 9687656)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-07', 9414929)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-08', 9346114)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-10', 11191780)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-11', 11277218)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-12', 10685228)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-13', 9501986)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-14', 9392314)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-17', 8759532)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-18', 8608039)
GO

INSERT INTO cbl (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'CD      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-20', 8728906)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-01', 79486981)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-02', 79775149)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-04', 80172336)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-05', 80613180)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-06', 80875268)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-07', 80850415)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-08', 80825368)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-09', 80689656)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-11', 80880419)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-12', 81183129)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-13', 80885495)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-14', 80667155)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-15', 80964480)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-16', 80695527)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (2, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-07-18', 81187061)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-01', 35268659)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-02', 35990031)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-03', 35697305)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-04', 35789855)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-06', 35974875)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-07', 35986519)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-08', 35820503)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-09', 35893017)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-10', 36101306)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-11', 36000306)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-13', 35962087)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-14', 35265973)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-15', 36389580)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-16', 35934011)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (3, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2010-12-18', 35520205)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-01', 42941552)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-03', 43432313)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-04', 43278596)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-05', 43211976)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-06', 43510036)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-07', 43512131)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-08', 43712267)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-10', 43845899)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-11', 43884868)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-12', 43613109)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-13', 43175944)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-14', 42326995)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-15', 42250329)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-17', 42053709)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (4, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2011-01-18', 42041652)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-01', 43800572)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-03', 43488437)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-04', 43616832)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-05', 44263415)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-06', 44148282)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-07', 43977058)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-08', 43757866)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-10', 44298331)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-11', 44204790)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-12', 44234531)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-13', 44268652)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-14', 44451762)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-17', 44130608)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-18', 44055977)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.D010014 (LBrCode, PrdAcctId, CblDate, Balance4)
VALUES (6, 'SB      000000000000000000000000', '2009-08-20', 43866291)
GO
```

```
create table hrk_test (report_date datetime, dname char(15))

with cte as (
select cast('01-jan-2017' as date) xdtat
union all
select dateadd(day,1,xdate) from cte
where xdate <cast('31-dec-2020' as date)
)
select * into hrk_test from cte
```

I have posted here a sample data
desire result is balnce4 for all the dates from @mdt
Please help
**'Stack is not allowing me to save the edits'**

this is not

Comment: where #Temp coming in the code ?

Comment: I tried select * into #temp from after select @hrk=a from @mdt where srno=@a but able to save only first record.

Comment: @hemu_k VenkataramanR is correct `where rnk=1` filters out all but the first row.

Comment: @Dale K  I hae partitioned the data on lbrcode and prdacctid so rnk=1 gives me the latest row for a given product of a given lbrcode

Comment: @hemu_k my point (and VenkataramanR's) is that your syntax for inserting into a temp table is 100% correct... therefore the query cannot be returning the correct results. The only way we can help you further is if you provide a [mre] i.e. a dbfiddle with test data which demonstrates the issue, i.e. shows that the query returns different results to the temp table - I don't believe its possible.

Comment: So many problems. But your code (as posted) throws an error which you rather conveniently ignore. You can't use "select ... into #temp" in a loop since you cannot create the temp table multiple times - only the first execution will succeed. Create your temp table before the loop and then populate it with the standard insert statement. That will at least allow the code to run successfully (assuming no other logic errors). There is much to learn here.

Comment: Why is this a `while` loop and a table variable, it could just be one joined query

Answer (score 0):

You are getting single row, because you are having rnk = 1. If you want multiple rows, you need to apply rnk filter accordingly.

```sql
select *  INTO #temp from 
(
select LBrCode,rtrim(substring(PrdAcctId,1,8)) prdcd,Balance4,@hrk xdate,
rank() over (partition by LBrCode,PrdAcctId order by CblDate desc ) rnk
from cbl where CblDate <=@hrk  and floor(substring(PrdAcctId,17,8))=0
) x where rnk=1 and prdcd='CC' -- and LBrCode=1
```

Now, pull data from #temp

```sql
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Comment: if i do not use into statement i get the desired result  e,g ```1 CC -66609058.78 2020-10-09 1
2 CC -351468.35 2020-10-09 1
3 CC -21327017.85 2020-10-09 1
4 CC -12924417.73 2020-10-09 1
5 CC -10947054.06 2020-10-09 1
6 CC -6903779.1 2020-10-09 1
99 CC 0 2020-10-09 1```

Comment: yes. if you INTO clause, data gets inserted to #temp table

Comment: @ Venkat..R Removing rnk=1 will not solve the problem

Comment: @hemu_k, yes. just insert and select from #temp, as I have mentioned in answer

Comment: @venkatramana R no sir i get only first date but i am storing below dates in mdt table 2020-10-09 1
2020-10-23 2
2020-11-06 3
2020-11-20 4
2020-12-04 5
2020-12-18 6

Comment: @hemu_k this code is correct for inserting the query into a temp table and then selecting from a temp table. If you are not getting the expected results then your original query is wrong. Really you need to provide sample data (as DDL+DML) and expected results (as tabular text) in order for us to assist.

Comment: @Dale K sir query is correct  cbl table contains data of the day on which transaction is done on a particular product  e,g.  In India we have a National Holiday on 15th Aug so there will not be a single transaction in cbl as on 15th Aug However If i need a balance as on 15th Aug i use rank() function ordering data on cbldate desc and pick where rank=1.  here I am trying the same for given dates . I am Actually getting the result in output but want to store it in table for further processing and same is not being achieved by me